# iphone - make a list of buttons appear from below

Tags: iphone, xcode

I would add a drop down list of buttons that appear/disappear from below side, as the "share button" in the native iphone. How  can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The share view is an UIActivityController object and you can only use it to share and so on.

The best thing is to create a custom UIView and place your buttons in it. Then you sinply animate it into the visible part of the screen and then again out. If you need a simple code example let me know.

Update:

```
// Create your UIView and connect in your storyboard/XIB
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] init];

// Add the UIButtons to your UIView
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[myView addSubview:button];

// Animate the UIView that contains the buttons
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.15];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 740, 768, 264);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```